# how would you recreate this animation in framer motion?

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion, react-animated

I want to know how to recreate this animation in framer motion:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6M819hVz-oo
@1:19

where his Occupation pops up
I've tried to recreate this but I can't get past a simple fade as you can see there is a white block there that makes it look like it's coming out of the bottom.

this is my very simple motion component :

```
 <motion.h4
    initial={{
      
      y:50,
      color:'blue'
    }}
    transition={{duration:.4}}
    animate={{
      color:'black',
      
      y:0,
      
    }}
    >first Last </motion.h4>
```

Comment: it takes a while to understand what you mean. Ok, for that to happen, you have to paint white to the bottom part of your text deliberately. I know it's already white. But you have to paint another element with `z-index` higher than the text.

Comment: You can animate the text inside a div with a fixed height and `overflow: hidden`.